# How do I match values?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I've got a problem where I want to place values in an array at certain matching values.

I've got `displacement_gsj_values` filled with values I want to transplant, `displacement_gsj_match` filled with the corresponding value match (in order) and `displacement_all` a bigger array filled with corresponding matches of displacement_gsj.

Example:

```
displacement_gsj_values = [[-3.4],[0],[3.874],[7.4],[0.55],[-0.98],[0],[9.99],[-0.35]]

displacement_gsj_match  = [[3],[4],[5],[9],[10],[11],[15],[16],[17]]

displacement_all = [[0],[0],[0],[3],[4],[5],[0],[0],[0],[9],[10],[11],[0],[0],[0],[9],[15],[11],[16],[4],[5],[9],[17],[11]]
```

---

I thought about a loop that should do this:

```
for i in displacement_all:
    if i != 0:
        if i in displacement_all[i] == displacement_gsj_match["any value of displacement_gsj_match with the same value of i"]:
            displacement_all[i] = displacement_gsj_values["the index of the above matched value"]
    
    else:
        pass
```

It should place the values of `displacement_gsj_values` with the corresponding index out of `displacement_gsj_match` (both in order) into displacement_all at the matching value.
The result should look like this:

```
displacement_all = [[0],[0],[0],[-3.4],[0],[3.874],[0],[0],[0],[7.4],[0.55],[-0.98],[0],[0],[0],[7.4],[0],[-0.98],[9.99],[0],[3.874],[7.4],[-0.35],[-0.98]]
```

Had to post it again because someone just answered and then deleted his answer.

Comment: First of all, it's not clear why you thought that someone deleting their answer meant that you needed to delete and repost this. Second, it's not clear what behavior you're trying to implement here; you seem to be inserting 0's into `displacement_gsj_values` according to some unclear logic.  Perhaps you can make a smaller illustrative example.

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason that you're using a nested list, i.e. `[[3],[4],[5],[9],[10],[11],[15],[16],[17]]` instead of `[3,4,5,9,10,11,15,16,17]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first of all create a dictionary that maps values to their replacement:

```
# Flatten the list of lists
displacement_gsj_match = sum(displacement_gsj_match, [])
displacement_gsj_values = sum(displacement_gsj_values, [])

# Create dictionary with match as key and replacement as value
replacements = dict(zip(displacement_gsj_match, displacement_gsj_values))
```

Looks like this and makes substitution easier:

```
{3: -3.4,
 4: 0,
 5: 3.874,
 9: 7.4,
 10: 0.55,
 11: -0.98,
 15: 0,
 16: 9.99,
 17: -0.35}
```

Then you go over your list and check if the value can be replaced or stays the same. I used the `get()` function, where the second argument is the default value. This means if the value is in the dictionary you replace it otherwise default to the existing value:

```
new_displacement = [[replacements.get(x[0], x[0])] for x in displacement_all]
```

Output:

```
[[0],
 [0],
 [0],
 [-3.4],
 [0],
 [3.874],
 [0],
 [0],
 [0],
 [7.4],
 [0.55],
 [-0.98],
 [0],
 [0],
 [0],
 [7.4],
 [0],
 [-0.98],
 [9.99],
 [0],
 [3.874],
 [7.4],
 [-0.35],
 [-0.98]]
```

P.S.: This could be done in many ways, but I find this one pretty good to understand.

Comment: It works!! Thank you, very informative! replacements = dict(zip(displacement_gsj_match, displacement_gsj_values)) should be replaced with replacements = dict(zip(displacement_gsj_values, displacement_gsj_match))

Comment: Glad I could help! Not sure why you want to switch `match` and `values`, but it only has to work for your specific problem.

Comment: Nah u right. I just got mixed up. Yours is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way would be to directly use a comprehension:

```
[lst if lst[0] == 0
     else displacement_gsj_values[displacement_gsj_match.index(lst)]
     for lst in displacement_all]
```

which gives as expected:

```
[[0], [0], [0], [-3.4], [0], [3.874], [0], [0], [0], [7.4], [0.55], [-0.98], [0],
 [0], [0], [7.4], [0], [-0.98], [9.99], [0], [3.874], [7.4], [-0.35], [-0.98]]
```